# SQL Server (Linked Server)

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server, vb.net, linked-server

My database is from a linked server and I have a problem with my connection string in ASP.NET (web.config) it says that :
Database schema could not be retrieved for this connection. Please make sure the connection settings are correct and that the database is online. Cannot open database "AA" requested by the login. The login failed. Login failed for user 'sa' at DataObjectSupport(423,6)

I try to use this connection string.

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="localconnection" connectionString="Data Source=SERVERNAME;Persist Security Info=True;Initial Catalog=database; uid=sa; Password=password; " providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

Comment: Given that the `sa` account (which has full control of the SQL Server instance and so definitely should not be used from applications) can see and manage every database in the instance... are you sure that the instance to which you're connecting actually has a database named `AA`? Do you have multiple instances installed? Could you be connecting to the wrong one?